# Bug? GXT (Ext GWT) Compiles in 'devmode' target but not for 'build'

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm working on a GXT project, and I'm using GXT UiBinder. I'm compiling with `ant`. The target `devmode` works fine with no errors, and I'm able to see my application running in the browser. But using the target `build` I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/webbtra/dev/rail_gxt/gxt-2.2.3/gxt.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/data/BeanModelLookup.java'
[ERROR] Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but interface was expected
```

I'm using these versions, which I've read that they should be compatible:

- GWT Version: 2.1.1 (also tried 2.2.0 and 2.0.4 with same result)
- GXT Version: 2.2.3

Compilation will work if I remove `<inherits name="com.jhickman.web.gwt.gxtuibinder.GxtUiBinder" />` from my module file, and use only GWT components. But again, it's strange that it works fine in `devmode`. Any help is appreciated.

-tjw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Even though GXT 2.2.3 **claims** to be compatible with GWT 2.2, it isn't. I reverted back to GXT 2.2.1 and GWT 2.0.4 and it works perfectly.

Comment: This old by now, but this might be useful for future readers: GXT 2 ships with 3 jars, one for GWT 1.7 (suffixed with -gwt17), one for GWT 2.0 to 2.1.x (-gwt2), and one for GWT 2.2.x and onward (-gwt22). Make very certain that no extra copies of GWT are sitting on the classpath, bringing old versions of classes. And hopefully GWT won't break binary compatibility again in the near future.

Comment: @Colin that comment fixed my problem. If you put that as an answer I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the exact same error message you posted (even without using GxtUiBinder!), but I accidentally had set my GWT SDK to 2.1.1 (in Eclipse). I'm using "gxt-2.2.3-gwt22.jar", so this obviously cannot work.

Switching the GWT SDK to 2.2.0 solved the problem. So it seems, that GXT 2.2.3 + GWT 2.2.0 work together just fine.

If you'd like to try it again, make sure, that you don't just change the GWT library, but really switch the GWT SDK. (eg in Eclipse: *Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit > Use specific SDK*)

Answer (score 1):

I'm managed to have them compiling together (gwt 2.2 + GXT 2.2.3) , but GWT Designer (Window Builder too) started throwing exceptions while parsing code. Without GXT - everything is fine. Becouse of Designer bug, i'm forced to downgrade GWT.